# How to select and display multiple columns using loc in python

Tags: python-3.x

Assume I have a data frame (`ds`) like this:

```
ID Name Age                
1  xxc 34               
2  sfg 23    
3  hdg 18
```

I want to display the columns `Name` and `Age` as well.

Currently through this line of code

```
def item(id):
   return ds.loc[ds['ID'] == id]['Name'].tolist()[0]
```

I am able to get only `Name` column value. How do I get `Age` column value too?

Please note I want to retain the same code, i.e the return statement.
Any solutions please?

Comment: are you looking for something like `ds.loc[ds['ID'] == 1,['Name','Age']]`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. It partially solves the problem but when i want to store it into a list it becomes a problem. I basically want to store it into a list as I can later iterate over it.Any solution on how to get a fix for the 'tolist() part. Thanks for your response.

Comment: what type of list?? can you give an example of how you want the first row ie `xxc 34` should be in a list?

Comment: Yes, I want the first row to be xxc 34

Comment: But that is what the code is giving. In list format, how do you want that to be as a list?

Comment: The below line of code returns a Dataframe object.                                              
 return ds.loc[ds['ID'] == id]['Name']                                                                                     Hence I want to convert to a list. I get an error while converting to a list using ur solution.i.e while doing tolist()[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list(ds.loc[ds['ID'] == 1,['Name','Age']].iloc[0])
Out[365]: ['xxc', 34]
```